# sharepoint 2010 document library ip filtering

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to set up IP filtering in a SharePoint document library based on a group that a user is a member of. More specifically, we have groups set up for each of our customers. Each group should have an allowed IP address attached to it. When a user accesses this document library, we then need to ensure that the user is coming from the IP address attached to their customer group. The IP filtering would only apply to a single document library, not the entire site.

My only idea so far is to create a webpart that checks the user's IP address and redirects if it isn't correct. Then I could put that webpart at the top of a webpart page, and display the document library webpart below that. That's a little hokey, so I was hoping someone had a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your proposed solution of a webpart on the AllItems.aspx page is that there multiple ways to get to a document and this would not prevent someone with a direct URL from accessing the document.

You want to take advantage of SharePoint's permission structure.  If the documents can be grouped by security, then you could create one library per customer (or one folder within a single library) and set the permissions based on your SharePoint groups for the library/folder.  That may not work for you if you need to have one document that is available to multiple groups.

Another option is to set the library security to be restricted to only one system account.  Then you could write a webpart (or application page) that checked the user's IP address and using RunWithElevatedPermissions you could get the contents of the libary that are applicable to that user.  That would solve the issue of a direct link because they would have to go through your page to access the documents.

Comment: What do you think about using an HTTP module to check the IP address? Inside the module I would simply check the URL to see if I was accessing something in the restricted document library, and if I was, then look up the user's IP address and compare to my list. Thoughts?

Comment: That could certainly work.  It's not clear from your question if these restricted users will have access to other areas of your site.  If so, then you'd just have to allow the requests to be passed through if they were requesting a different area and only check the IP address for the library. But if everything is based on the IP address access, then an HTTP module could work well.

Comment: I should have been more clear. The IP filtering would only apply to a single extra-secure document library. The rest of the site would be permissions as usual.

I wrote up an http module and it seems to work. I know that there is overhead on every page in the entire site because of it. The first line in the handler is to check the path, and if it starts with /Downloads (the site that is extra-secure), then I go on and do the IP check. It seems to work pretty well. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you have a good solution.  The small overhead is needed by your business requirements and shouldn't add any noticeable time to the page loads.